# Why does my text fade in but my html canvas object won't?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, fadein

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/7y9Gp/2/

I'm still not sure what's wrong. I can fade in text or an image (including fade-out) but my canvas object won't do either no matter what i try. Any help would be appreciated! I even switched the canvas location with the text (in the code) but nope. Is there a particular way to fade canvas objects in?

### HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picOne').delay(1000).fadeIn(2000).delay(2500);
    $('#picTwo').delay(500).fadeIn(2500).delay(2000);
    $('#picThree').delay(4000).fadeIn(2500).delay(2000);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pics" align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>

<td valign="middle" align="center">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

        <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><font size="200" id="picOne" color="black">SOME TEXT</font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td align="center" valign="middle">        

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/trail/01/js/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/trail/01/js/trail.js"></script>



<div id="picTwo">
<canvas width="640" height="480" id="my-image"></canvas>
</div>
</td>
        </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

​

### CSS:

```
#picOne, #picTwo {
position:relative;
display: none;
float:center;
    top: 280px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#pics {
}


#my-image {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}​
```

Comment: Please check your js fiddle. It is completely broken. You can select framework in left panel. Script panel should not have `<script>` tags, you should use absolute URLs to connect external scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7y9Gp/11/

You expect to find a canvas in `div#picTwo`, but `trail.js` or `three.js` creates own canvas (or something like that - I did not look deeper). So, if you will replace:

```
$('#picTwo').delay(500).fadeIn(2500).delay(2000);
```

with

```
$('canvas').delay(500).fadeOut(2500).delay(2000);
```

It will work fine  (`fadeIn` replaced with `fadeOut` just to show that it works, because it is visible by default and fadeIn will have no effect)

So, basically the only problem is that you are trying to `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` wrong object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However when I try to fade it in it doesn't work :/ Only with a fade out.

Comment: You should read what I have placed in brackets after `It will work fine` again. fadeIn does not work because canvas is already visible and it can not be done "more visible" ;) Try `$('canvas').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(2500).delay(2000);`

Comment: Oh my bad! And that worked amazing!!! Thanks so much I totally didn't know about the hide value!!!!